# How do I specify multiple activities in AndroidManifest one for splash screen, one for mainactivity - pass the original intent to the mainactivy

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I am only new to android this is my first application.

I am making progress on an app that fires when the NFC reader detects a TAG that contains NDEF messages, specifically when a URL is detect matching my domain.

I would like to add a splashscreen that fires  triggered by the Android INTENT of but then passes the original INTENT to the mainactivity for further processing, I have made a start but not sure how to marry up the manifest and code to do what I am after.

MANIFEST.XML

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="<my custom domain>"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any help on how I should structure my Manifest to deal with this scenario, the SplashScreenActivity I could use the intent filters here to ensure that it is triggered, but then I create a new intent which means losing the NDEF extras.

```
    public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to "just pass" the whole original INTENT to the mainactivity but I am unsure how to do this.

Here is the code that extracts the NDEF messages from the INTENT any ideas appreciated.

```
private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
    

    String action = intent.getAction();


    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action) ||
            NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        logViewModel.insert(new LogEntry("READFROMINTENT ACTUALLY FIRED", "Action " + intent.getExtras()));
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
            getNdefRecords(msgs);
            addLinkToDbFromRecord(records);
        }
        //buildTagViews(msgs);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve this by doing the following.

I moved my intent filters from MainActivity to the .splashscreen actvity changed the category of mainactivity to DEFAULT, and allowed splashscreen activity to remain the LAUNCHER

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme..NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.myap.app.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp.SplashTheme">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="my domain"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In my splashscreen activity i used the following code to copy the extras from the original intent, set the action to the expected action the mainactivity was designed to handle and used this to start the main activity

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        startMainActivity.putExtras(getIntent());

        startMainActivity.setAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        startActivity(startMainActivity);

        finish();
    }
}
```